# UUID Generated Values with Hibernate and Postgres

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, liquibase

I have a question about UUID generated values.

We are using Hibernate/JPA for our persistence, and Liquibase for DDL.

If we define a table such as:

```
<changeSet author=".." id="1234-create-books">
  <createTable tableName="books">
    <column name="id" type="UUID" defaultValueComputed="uuid_generate_v1mc()">
      <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="pk_books"/>
    </column>
    ...
  </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

But then define the Entity like:

```
@Entity
public static class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;
    
    ...
}
```

Can I confirm that Hibernate would take precedence, and [generate a UUID value](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-uuid) using:

> The default strategy is a version 4 (random) strategy according to IETF RFC 4122.

As opposed to using the v1 strategy defined with default value computed?

Comment: Why not generate a V4 UUID in Postgres as well, e.g. using the built-in `gen_random_uuid()`?

Comment: We were actually looking to use v1 UUIDs, and wanted to check that an inadvertent GeneratedValue would negate default value computed or not..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's how SQL works. A default for a column is only used when you are not mentioning the column in an insert, but Hibernate will always set a value for the id column in inserts.
If you want to use `uuid_generate_v1mc()`, you will have to write a custom `IdentifierGenerator`. See https://thorben-janssen.com/custom-sequence-based-idgenerator/ for an example.